# configuring cmake to display fewer percentage indicators

Tags: makefile, cmake

Is there a way to customize CMake so that the `make` command doesn't show every single percentage progress? For example,  right now my build shows

```
[  1%] Building Fortran object dep/CMakeFiles/depuqtk.dir/blas/cgerc.f.o
[  2%] Building Fortran object dep/CMakeFiles/depuqtk.dir/blas/cgeru.f.o
[  3%] Building Fortran object dep/CMakeFiles/depuqtk.dir/blas/cscal.f.o
[  4%] Building Fortran object dep/CMakeFiles/depuqtk.dir/blas/csscal.f.o
```

and etcetera, but I would like cmake to display

```
[  5% ] Building Fortran object dep/CMakeFiles/depuqtk.dir/blas/cgerc.f.o
[  10%] Building Fortran object dep/CMakeFiles/depuqtk.dir/blas/cgeru.f.o
[  15%] Building Fortran object dep/CMakeFiles/depuqtk.dir/blas/cscal.f.o
[  20%] Building Fortran object dep/CMakeFiles/depuqtk.dir/blas/csscal.f.o
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to assume it goes through all the percentage numbers eventually? So you don't really mean you want *those* lines to read that way and you mean you want it to only show occasionally percentage markers? And I seriously doubt you can control this.

Comment: The question is whether you wish to skip the information about files being compiled completely or just wish to skip some of percentage marks?

Comment: You get one line per object file. The percentage is just calculated and added. Compile CMake itself and you will see, that several lines have the same percentage figure in front of them. On the other hand, if you only have one object file, it will immediately jump to 100%.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the [`RULE_MESSAGES`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_gbl/RULE_MESSAGES.html) target property to `OFF` to *"disable granular messages and report only as each target completes"*:

```
set_target_properties(some_target PROPERTIES RULE_MESSAGES OFF)
```

You can also do this globally, or from the command line, by setting the `CMAKE_RULE_MESSAGES` variable to `OFF`. E.g.:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_RULE_MESSAGES=OFF /path/to/source
```

(Note that this currently only works for Makefile generators.)